# How to improve performance joining tables with no primary keys

Tags: sql-server

Given two large tables of ~8,000,000 rows each. They are being joined on substrings of

- name
- address
- zipcode

Naturally, the query is taking a long time. What are the best methods to improve it

Comment: Does "no primary keys" = "no indexes"? And how exactly are you joining, exact string matches or are you using patterns/LIKE?

Comment: Do a DESC <table_name> \G for both tables. And provide your joining query. What's a "long time"?

Comment: In addition to Aaron's comment, what version of SQL Server are you using and can you make ddl changes to the tables?

Comment: @Vérace I don't recognise the DESC syntax, how does one enter that? I'm more familiar with using sp_help <table_name>

Comment: Sorry - I used MySQL syntax. DESCribe - it's not the DESCending in SQL, it's describe the table - or SHOW CREATE TABLE - or whatever it is in SQL Server. Give us the table structure and whatever indexes already exist. Show us the query also. Does SQL Server have functional indexes? Virtual fields? I'm thinking something along those lines.